# Python convert a list of string to integer with a formula

Tags: python, integer

I can simply convert a string to integer with a formula, for example:

```
lines = '0x61'
(int(lines ,16)*2+128+100)*0.002
```

This outputs: 0.844

If I have a list of strings, I then won't be able to put in the `int()`.

```
lines = ['0x83',
'0x00',
'0x7D',
'0x00',
'0x90']
(int(lines ,16)*2+128+100)*0.002
```

This output an error: `int() can't convert non-string with explicit base`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Be careful assigning to the name `str` — it's a built-in type.

Comment: What are you expecting to get when you convert a list to an int?

Comment: If you want to perform the formula on each element, use a list comprehension.

Comment: Thanks @Kwinkunks, I revised str to lines. I expects to print a list of number after conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over the entries, or put it in a list comprehension:

```
>>> strings = ['0x83', '0x00', '0x7D', '0x00', '0x90']
>>> [(int(s, 16)*2+128+100)*0.002 for s in strings]
[0.98, 0.456, 0.9560000000000001, 0.456, 1.032]
```

If it was me I'd probably make a little function to keep it tidy:

```
def transform(s: str) -> float:
    """Transform strings to floats."""
    return (int(s, 16)*2+128+100)*0.002

strings = ['0x83', '0x00', '0x7D', '0x00', '0x90']
[transform(s) for s in strings]
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to loop over a list, for example using a list comprehension:

```
list_of_strings = ['0x83', '0x00', '0x7D', '0x00', '0x90']
[(int(item,16)*2+128+100)*0.002 for item in list_of_strings]
```

Outputs:

```
[0.98, 0.456, 0.9560000000000001, 0.456, 1.032]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the elements in the list.

```
str1 = ['0x83',
'0x00',
'0x7D',
'0x00',
'0x90']
for str2 in str1:
    integer=(int(str2,16)*2+128+100)*0.002
    print(integer)
```

You are literally trying to convert a list to an integer. This is the cause of the error.